# Calling class method within _cp_dispatch doesn't work?

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

I'm trying to call a cherrypy exposed class method within a _cp_dispatch method, e.g.:

```
class ABC(object):

@cherrypy.expose
def post(self):
    return "POSTING"

def _cp_dispatch(self, vpath):
    if len(vpath) == 1:
        return self.post()
    return vpath
```

However the "post" method doesn't get called unless i change it to index(self), and tell _cp_dispatch to return self. Otherwise, when i enter a url 8080:/ABC, i get a 404 error saying `path to /ABC/ not found` 
What is the issue here?

Is it just not possible to create multiple methods for a single URL path using cherrypy?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

just ended up creating a second class to hold the get and post methods. Full code looks like this:

```
import cherrypy
import random
import string

class data(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.catalogue = catalogue()

def _cp_dispatch(self, vpath):
    if len(vpath) == 1:
        return self.catalogue

    return vpath

class catalogue(object):
exposed = True

@cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
def GET(self):
    return cherrypy.session['mystring']

def POST(self, length=8):
    some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
    cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
    return some_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
conf = {
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(data(),'/',conf)
```